# infinite loop in appropriate solution

Tags: python, loops

I am no clue of why I have the infinite loop for the codes below. Thank you for telling me and answer!

```
cube = 25
epision = 0.01
guess = 0
increment = 0.01
while abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epision:
    guess += increment
if abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epision:
    print("Failed on cube root of", cube)
else:
    print (guess, 'is close to the cube root of',cube)
```

Comment: The `if` can never be true, since the loop would repeat if it were.

Comment: Why would you expect the loop to ever end?

Comment: Consider `guess**3 - cube`.  Guess starts at 0, so it's -25.  Then it becomes 1 and it's -24.  Then it becomes 2 and it's -17.  Then it becomes 3 and it's 2.  From that point on, the difference is always positive and just gets larger with each iteration.  The problem is that adding 1 to guess starts moving it further from the desired value rather than closer.  This isn't really a Python problem, it's an algorithm problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even at it's closest, the absolute difference between `guess**3` and `cube` is still `0.10291200000046885` and thus larger than `epsilon`.

To fix it, you could:

- use a larger `epsilon` or smaller `increment`
- or compare the absolute difference to the difference in the last iteration and `break` once it stars to rise again
- or just check whether `guess**3 > cube`, since you are testing from `0` anyway and not doing e.g. binary search

Or, actually *use* [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm); it's a much better algorithm, converging much faster to the target, and for an (almost) arbitrarily small epsilon, and not that hard to implement:

```
lower, upper = 0, cube # cube root has to be between these two numbers
while abs(guess**3 - cube) >= epision:
    if guess**3 > cube:
        guess, upper = (guess + lower) / 2, guess
    else:
        guess, lower = (guess + upper) / 2, guess
```

Answer (score 0):

The cube root of `25` is about `2.92402`.

When `guess = 2.92`, `guess ** 3 = 24.897`, so `abs(guess ** 3 - cube) == 0.103`, which is not less than `epsilon`. So you add `0.01` to `guess`.

When `guess = 2.93`, `guess ** 3 = 25.154`, so `abs(guess ** 3 - cube) = 0.154`, which is also not less than `epsilon`.

As you keep adding `0.01` to `guess`, you'll get further away, so the loop continues infinitely.